# UITableView sections based on substringToIndex

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having trouble putting sections in my tableView. All of the data is there and coming up in table view, until I add in my code to section by name.

This is my code for getting the array and sectioning by name:

```
-(void)setupReportsFromJSONArray:(NSData*)dataFromReportsArray{
    BOOL found;
    NSError *error;
   // NSMutableArray *reportsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *arrayFromServer = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromReportsArray options:0 error:&error];

    if(error){
        NSLog(@"error parsing the json data from server with error description - %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    else {
        reportsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(NSDictionary *eachReport in arrayFromServer)
        {

            ReportsDataObject *report = [[ReportsDataObject alloc] initWithJSONData:eachReport];

            [reportsArray addObject:report];
            NSString *c = [[eachReport objectForKey:@"title"] substringToIndex:1];
            found = NO;

            for (NSString *str in [self.sections allKeys])
            {
                if ([str isEqualToString:c])
                {
                    found = YES;
                }
            }

            if (!found)
            {
                [self.sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:c];
            }
        }

        }
        NSLog(@"Array Populated");
        NSLog(@"%u reports found",reportsArray.count);
        //Now you have your reportsArray filled up with all your data objects



for (NSDictionary *eachReport in arrayFromServer)
{
    [[self.sections objectForKey:[[eachReport objectForKey:@"title"] substringToIndex:3]] addObject:eachReport];
}

// Sort each section array
for (NSString *key in [self.sections allKeys])
{
    [[self.sections objectForKey:key] sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES]]];
 [reportsTable reloadData];

}

}


-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.sections allKeys] count];
}




- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{


    {
        return [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section]] count];
    }
}
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return [[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    }





-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{


    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";



    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {


        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }

        //The beauty of this is that you have all your data in one object and grab WHATEVER you like
    //This way in the future you can add another field without doing much.

    if([reportsArray count] == 0){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"no reports to show";
    }
    else{





//        ReportsDataObject *currentReport = [reportsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//        cell.textLabel.text = [currentReport reportName];







        // in the future you can grab whatever data you need like this
        //[currentReport buildingName], or [currentReport reportName];
    }


    return(cell);







@end
```

This loads an empty screen in my tableView. Any ideas on where I went wrong? I took the basis of this code form a tutorial and I have tried to change it to benefit me, as these details came from a tutorial using a plist.

I have tried this in a variety of ways and this is the first way I have done this code that has not resulted in the app terminating.

If I were to NSLog this code, where is the best place to log so that I will get beneficial information?

EDIT WITH CHANGES

Here is the new NSLog requests I have entered based on additional help:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    NSUInteger count = [[self.sections allKeys] count];
    NSLog(@"Number of sections: %d", count);
    return count;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    {
        NSUInteger count = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section]] count];
        NSLog(@"Number of rows in section: %d", count);
        return count;
    }
}
```

NSLog Output stack:

```
2014-03-17 15:43:52.189 TESG-iConnect[14502:a0b] Array Populated
2014-03-17 15:43:52.189 TESG-iConnect[14502:a0b] 84 reports found
2014-03-17 15:43:52.190 TESG-iConnect[14502:a0b] Number of sections: 5
2014-03-17 15:43:52.191 TESG-iConnect[14502:a0b] Number of rows in section: 0
2014-03-17 15:43:52.191 TESG-iConnect[14502:a0b] Number of rows in section: 0
2014-03-17 15:43:52.192 TESG-iConnect[14502:a0b] Number of rows in section: 0
2014-03-17 15:43:52.192 TESG-iConnect[14502:a0b] Number of rows in section: 0
2014-03-17 15:43:52.192 TESG-iConnect[14502:a0b] Number of rows in section: 0
```

Comment: Could be a variety of things, but here are some tips and things you should look at changing: 1. You're doing a lot of sorting in methods that are called N times (where N is your dataset size). Look at sorting when you first get the data and don't worry about it after. It could help to not have them in dictionaries so they stay sorted. 2. For log statements, I would put them in "numberOfSectionsInTableView" to see what number you're returning, as well as "numberOfRowsInSection" to start. That way you know how many rows and sections your table thinks it has! Look at storing your data differently

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your reply. I originally tried to sort the data initially but I couldn't figure out how to do it without breaking what I had already done. do you have any hints on where to start with that? Also the numberOfSectionsInTableView uses the self.sections allKeys property to get that data, how would I then NSLog that? i tried a few different ways but it keeping erroring out

Comment: No problem! You're actually grabbing the count already in numberOfSections, an easy way would just be to have an intermediate NSUInteger variable. Try adding "NSUInteger count = [[self.sections allKeys] count];" followed by "NSLog(@"Number of sections: %d", count);". You can do the same for numberOfRowsInSection, just replace the return with "NSUInteger count = " and then return count after printing it.

Comment: Also, in setupReportsFromJSONArray when you loop through the keys to determine if you have that section or not already, you can just try to grab the object for that key with "NSMutableArray *array = [self.sections objectForKey: c];". If array is nil, it means there is no current object for that key. Otherwise, the key already exists! If you want to have it stored differently though, I would look at holding the data in NSMutableArrays. That way, at the end of setupReportsFromJSONArray, you can sort the data and know it will stay sorted for you.

Comment: Thanks for that Ryan. Nothing logged in the Output stack between the NSLog for Array Populated and the new NSLogs for numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: Wait so "Array Populated" never showed up? And the new NSLogs didn't appear either?

Comment: no Array Populated showed up, and so did %u reports found (logged as 84 reports found) but there is nothing logging after that.

Comment: Okay! I would look at seeing if the delegate and data source is set up properly. In your viewDidLoad, try setting reportsTable.delegate = self; as well as reportsTable.dataSource = self;

Comment: I added the delegates as suggested with the same result, although it is worth noting that the delegate and datasource were already set through the storyboard, however i figured it can't hurt to try  :-)

Comment: Okay, cool! Ah one big thing as well - right now the reportsTable is being told to reloadData in every single iteration of [self.sections allKeys]. I would move the reloadData OUTSIDE of that loop, underneath. Double-check to make sure that reportsTable is hooked up, and maybe set a breakpoint before [reportsTable reloadData] to make sure it's not nil.

Comment: OK…we have…SOMETHING lol. Once I moved the reloadData to outside that loop, i ran the simulator and the Output stack showed Number of sections: 0 I have also inserted the break point where you suggested, but I don't know how to find out if reportsTable is nil...

Comment: Hey that's something! Did you remember to allocate and initialize your self.sections array?

Comment: sorry I'm confused lol. I thought self.sections was a dictionary. or are you talking about the NSMutableArray code you suggested earlier? I am still fairly new to this so easily confused haha

Comment: Oops sorry about that, yes dictionary haha. You need to make sure that you initialize the dictionary so it will store your data. Try self.sections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; in your viewDidLoad

Comment: ok that worked more than it has so far!! I have more data in my Output stack now but the sections is not coming up right. At top left, in what looks like 1 section, I have A C I O P descending. these letters I am assuming should be showing on the right as an index. also numberOfRowsInSection is logging data data 5 times. I will edit question to show the stack

Comment: Okay, that's a good thing that it's being logged 5 times, as it's being called once for each section. Just so I'm clear, what exactly are you trying to accomplish at a high level? I've got to run for now but will come back tomorrow and check in.

Comment: OK No probs. I have customers that will log in to see their reports. These reports all begin with Audit, POT, Annual etc etc. Basically I would like the reports to section in the table view by their report name. At this stage one of the report names is only 3 characters (POT) so I need to index the first 3 characters of the report name and use that to name each section. Eventually I would also like to make these 3 characters an alias, so that I can actually use them to section by the full report type i.e. Annual Passive (currently Annual), Path Of Travel (currently POT) if this is possible

Comment: UPDATE - I figured out why data wasn't showing and have fixed that issue. Now I just have to figure out the naming side of it. Also, do you know how to display the names as section names but not have the index at the right hand side??

Comment: Sorry about the delay it's been a crazy week! To get rid of the index on the right hand side, just remove the "sectionIndexTitlesForTableView" call, and that should make them disappear.

Comment: awesome man thanks :-) don't worry about the delay, it's all good!!